# cygwin's ps -W doesn't show all processes when running through an ssh session

Tags: cygwin, ps, cygwin-sshd

I hope this is the right place to ask this question: I have two machines (Win7) running cygwin. Machine A connects to Machine B through an ssh session. When I run `ps -W` in the ssh terminal on A, the list of processes is missing some of the processes running on B (in particular, Visual Studio's `devenv.exe`). However, if I run `ps -W` on B directly, those missing processes are shown just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Does it seem to be a cygwin bug or am I misunderstanding `ps`/`ssh`?

Thanks.

**Edit:** it looks like even knowing the PID, I still can't kill the VS process from ssh session:

```
$ /bin/kill.exe -f 4728
kill: couldn't open pid 4728
```

So it looks like somehow ssh session does not have access to this process and therefore does not list it. Why is that happening?

Comment: Do `ps -V` are you using the same ps?

Comment: 1.7.15. Why would not they be the same (running one locally vs. running one through ssh?)

Comment: Does the user you're SSHing in as own the processes in question?

Comment: I was interested if the two versions were the same, and was going to check for bugs in your version. The user you log into via ssh, is this that same user that owns the process? Are you sure you are logging into the same machine as where the process is running? Paste some relevant output of `ps -W`, and `id`